Local files deleted by git pull
I added some changes from my local directory to the staging area, then committed and tried to push a subset. I got a message that I had to pull first, which I did, expecting that I would be asked about any conflicts. Instead, I have lost all the changes in my local directory, both those that were just added and those that I tried to commit.
Here are the error messages. First, this:
git pull origin master
remote: Enumerating objects: 11, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), 6.55 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
From https://github.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxx
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   b713141..adcf8c4  master     -> origin/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: LIST OF FILES

And then this.
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        .Rproj.user/1B350229/pcs/debug-breakpoints.pper
        .Rproj.user/1B350229/pcs/files-pane.pper
        .Rproj.user/1B350229/pcs/source-pane.pper
        .Rproj.user/1B350229/pcs/windowlayoutstate.pper
        .Rproj.user/1B350229/pcs/workbench-pane.pper
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
Index was not unstashed.
Merge with strategy ort failed.

I tried, without success, to recover with git fsck following suggestions here: Git checkout -- recover lost files
Are my local files lost or can I recover the ones I committed (but not pushed)? What about the files that I added but not committed?

To recover files that you committed, use git reflog to find the commit that has them. To recover staged, but not committed, files, you must use git fsck --lost-found. Don't follow these suggestions blindly. RTFM first!

Thanks @jonrsharpe. I have now recovered the code for the commit in the lost-found. But there isn't anything else in the file. How can I recover the original committed files? I have tried to RTFM, but still confused.

Run git reflog HEAD and locate the commit that has the files. Note the x in HEAD{x} of the commit or its SHA1. Then use get restore --source=HEAD{x} -- path/to/file. Beware, this will overwrite what you currently have in path/to/file; make sure it is not precious before you run the command.
